# WordPress, linking to a script file gets converted to CDATA

Tags: wordpress

Within the header.php, I have the following link to my script,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/_js/main.js"></script>
```

I have other links to various jQuery plugins as well, however this particular link when viewed in the browsers get converted to this....

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[

//MY SCRIPT CODE HERE

//]]></script>
```

Instead of it just linking to my script file, it outputs all the code within the file in the header. It doesn't do this with any other script document. Any ideas why this is happening?

Thank you

Comment: Try http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I have, haven't heard a response in months.

Comment: Does it happen if you disable all your plugins?  How about if you enqueue the script instead of adding the code directly to header.php (see [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) in the codex)?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the activity of a plugin that's trying to reduce the number of requests for the page.  As @Hobo suggests in the comments above, try disabling your plugins, & try the same code in another theme, & see if that has the same problem.  If not then you may need to find a way to work around this, or find another plugin.